# Holomorphic function defined as a series over a lattice

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $$ \Lambda = \{ m_1 w_1+ m_2 w_2 : m_1, m_2 \in \mathbb{Z} \}$$
where $ \{ w_1, w_2 \} $ is a basis of $ \mathbb{C} $ as a real vector space.

Consider the following series

$$ \sum_{\omega \in \Lambda} \frac{1}{(z - \omega)^3} $$
How can one prove that this series defines a holomorphic function on $ \mathbb{C}\setminus\Lambda $ ?

As the uniform limit of a sequence of holomorphic functions is holomorphic, it is sufficient to prove that the series converges uniformily in every compact set $ K \subset \mathbb{C}\setminus\Lambda$.

My question is how to prove that indeed the series converges uniformily in every compact set $ K \subset \mathbb{C}\setminus\Lambda$? I am having some trouble getting a good lower bound of $|z - \omega|^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is up to a constant the series for the derivative of the elliptic Weierstrass $\wp$-function, and you should find detailed treatments in any book on elliptic functions or any advanced complex analysis textbook.

Here is a rough sketch of the argument: Since this is a two-dimensional lattice, the number $N_r$ of lattice points $\omega$ in the disk $D_r = \{ |\omega| < r \}$ satisfies $N_r \le A r^2$ for some $A>0$. Now we split the sum up into the finite sum over the lattice points in the disk $D_0 = \{ |\omega| \le 2|z| \}$ and the series over the finite sums of lattice points in annuli $A_n = \{ 2^n |z| < |\omega| \le 2^{n+1} |z| \}$, i.e.,
$$
\sum_{\omega \in \Lambda} \frac{1}{(z-\omega)^3} = \sum_{\omega \in D_0 \cap \Lambda} \frac{1}{(z-\omega)^3} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{\omega \in A_n \cap \Lambda} \frac{1}{(z-\omega)^3}.
$$
Since the first sum is finite, it does not matter for questions of convergence. For the second (double) sum, we estimate each term using $|z-\omega| \ge |\omega| - |z| > (2^n-1) |z| \ge B \cdot 2^n$ for some positive constant $B$ (depending on $|z|$), so that $|z-\omega|^{-3}< B^{-3} \cdot 2^{-3n}$. The number of lattice points in $A_n$ is at most $N_{2^{n+1}} \le A \cdot 2^{2n+2} = 4A \cdot 2^{2n}$, so that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{\omega \in A_n \cap \Lambda} \frac{1}{|z-\omega|^3} \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty 4A \cdot 2^{2n} \cdot B^{-3} \cdot 2^{-3n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty C \cdot 2^{-n}
$$
with $C = 4A\cdot B^{-3}$, which gives us absolute convergence by comparison with a convergent geometric series.

Comment: Thank you. I will award you the bounty in 11 hours (can't do it now).

Comment: @W..: Somehow I forgot that you were asking about locally uniform convergence, but basically the same proof works.